Limit of sequence of non-negative, $C^0 \cap H^1$ functions that are zero at more and more points
I have a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions such that for each $n$, we got

$f_n \in H^1(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$
$f_n \geq 0$
$\lVert f_n \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C$ for a constant $C>0$ independent of $n$
$f_n(x_i^n) = 0$ for $i=1, ..., n$ where $\{x_i^n\}$ are $n$ points sampled from $\Omega$ from the uniform distribution

Due to the bounds we know that as $n \to \infty$, for a subsequence we have $f_n$ weakly converges to some $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ and strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$.
I want to conclude that the limit is zero in some sense. Because the functions are continuous and the gradients are uniformly bounded, I thought that this might hold (because then we can avoid steeper and steeper V shapes as the zeros get filled), but am unsure how to show this. If it's not true, could it be true if I assume $f_n \to f$ in $C^0(\bar\Omega)$?

If the dimension $d$ of $\Omega$ is at least $2$, you cannot say anything about the limit.
Indeed, from the non-embedding of $H_0^1$ into $C_0$, one can construct a function $\psi \in H_0^1(B)$, where $B \subset \mathrm R^d$ is the open unit ball, such that $\psi$ has a singularity at $0$ and $\psi \in C(B \setminus \{0\})$.
By scaling and truncation, one obtains functions $\phi_\varepsilon$ such that $\phi_\varepsilon \in H_0^1(B_\varepsilon) \cap C_0(B_\varepsilon)$ with values in $[0,1]$, such that $\phi_\varepsilon = 1$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and $\|\phi_\varepsilon\|_{H_0^1} \le \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary.
Now, let $f \in H_0^1(\Omega) \cap C_0(\Omega)$, $f \ge 0$, be arbitrary. We are going to modify $f$ slightly to obtain $f_n$. We use
$$
f_n := \max\bigg\{ f - \sum_{i = 1}^n f(x_i^n) \phi_{\varepsilon_n}(\cdot - x_i^n), 0\bigg\}.
$$
It is easy to check that $f_n(x_i^n) = 0$ and $\|f - f_n\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}$ is small if we choose $\varepsilon_n$ small enough.

This is a partial answer which should work as long as you are not in dimension $d=2$. I am assuming here that all the points $x_i^n$ are picked i.i.d.
Note first that for any open set $A$, the probability that $\{x^n_i \notin A \forall i \leq n, \text{ for infinitely  many n}\}$ is zero. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}(x^n_i \notin A \forall i \leq n) =(\frac{Leb(\Omega\setminus A)}{Leb(\Omega)})^n$, which is summable, so the result follows by Borel-Cantelli.
Therefore, if the sequence actually converges in $C(\overline{\Omega})$, the limit must be zero.
Indeed, there will exist $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$, $\|f_n-f\|_{sup}<\epsilon$. From this we conclude that for all $y^m_i$ with $m \geq N$, it holds that $|f(y^m_i)|<\epsilon$. In particular, by the above result, the set $\{y^m_i:m \geq N, i\leq m\}$ is dense in $\Omega$, and therefore, there exists a dense set on which $|f|<\epsilon$, so by continuity $|f|\leq \epsilon$ everywhere. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the result follows.
The question is a lot more subtle when we only care about $L^2$ convergence. The main computation is the following: Let $\chi$ be some continuous function with support in $[-1,1]$, so that looks like $1-|x|$ near zero. Then, consider $1-\chi(n|x|)$, which has support in $B_{\frac{1}{n}}$. The $H^1$ norm of this function in dimension $d$ is proportional to
$$
\int_{B_{\frac{1}{n}}}r^{d-1} n^2\|\chi'\|_{sup}^2 dr \sim n^{2-d}
$$
Therefore, in dimension $d>2$, you can have a bunch of very steep V shapes, as you mentioned in your question, so the limit does not have to be zero.
In dimension $d=1$ however, things are once again fine, since if $y_1^n, \dots y^n_n$ are the zeros for $f_n$, ordered from smallest to largest, you have that
$$
\int_{y_i^n}^{y_n^{i+1}}(f_n(y))^2dy = \int_{y_i^n}^{y_n^{i+1}}(\int_{y_i^n}^{y}f'_n(z)dz)^2dy\leq (y^{i+1}_n-y^i_n)^2\int_{y^i_n}^{y^{i+1}_n}(f'_n(z))^2dz
$$
where we have used Cauchy-Schwarz in the last line. Therefore, summing over $i$, we see that
$$
\|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \max_i\{(y^{i+1}_n-y^i_n)^2\}\|f'_n\|_{L^2}
$$
A Borel-Cantelli type argument will show again that $\max_i\{(y^{i+1}_n-y^i_n)^2\} \to 0$ almost surely, so that $\|f_n\|_{L^2}\to 0$, and therefore $f=0$.
Dimension $d=2$ probably requires a bit more care to answer in general...
